# Android Studio rename without refactor

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, rename

So, I want to rename a file in android studio (layout/resource files, etc...), but I want to do it safely. Basically, I want to rename without refactoring. I will take care of errors that come afterwards, but I don't want Android Studio to wreck havoc on some files that might not even have relations with the current file.

Basically, I want control on the renaming. A simple file rename. Is there a way to do it without having to go to Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two options and both inside the **Refactor** menu. The **Refactor> Rename** option is exactly what you don't want the other one **Refactor> Rename File** option is just what you want. Also when using **Refactor> Rename** it will show you the **Refactoring Preview**. There you see and select what is going to be affected by this change. To see options just right click

Comment: correct, but there is no way to rename resources this way, this will change code occurances as well. For resources renaming seems like it's needed to open Windows Explorer

Comment: No i updated my answer please check and remember you can always use right click exclude option to choose what is going to be affected from the refactoring.

Comment: yeah, now it's complete! Thanks for this answer!

Comment: I see no "rename file" option Android Studio 2.3.2. I only see rename. Oh wait, it's available on java files, but not on resource files. interesting...